# Count unique values for each group in multi column with criteria in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**UPDATED THE SAMPLE DATASET**

I have the following data:

```
location ID  Value
A        1   1 
A        1   1
A        1   1 
A        1   1
A        1   2 
A        1   2
A        1   2 
A        1   2
A        1   3 
A        1   4 
A        2   1 
A        2   2 
A        3   1 
A        3   2
B        4   1 
B        4   2 
B        5   1
B        5   1 
B        5   2
B        5   2 
B        6   1 
B        6   1
B        6   1
B        6   1 
B        6   1
B        6   2
B        6   2
B        6   2   
B        7   1
```

I want to count unique Values (only if value is equals to 1 or 2) for each location and for each ID for the following output.

```
location ID_Count  Value_Count
A        3         6
B        4         7
```

I tried using `df.groupby(['location'])['ID','value'].nunique()`, but I am getting only the unique count of values, like for I am getting value_count for A as 4 and for B as 2.

Comment: **UPDATE** - updated the dataset to reflect the actual problem. The values are also repeating and I need count for each ground and match ID as per the output required.

Answer (score 4):

Try `agg` with slice on `ID` on `True` values.

*For your updated sample, you just need to drop duplicates before processing. The rest is the same*

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['location', 'ID', 'Value'])

df_agg = (df.Value.isin([1,2]).groupby(df.location)
                              .agg(ID_count=lambda x: df.loc[x[x].index, 'ID'].nunique(), 
                                   Value_count='sum'))

Out[93]:
          ID_count  Value_count
location
A                3            6
B                4            7
```

Comment: Dropping duplicates is a clever idea. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, You can try `series.isin` with `groupby.agg`

```
out = (df.assign(Value_Count=df['Value'].isin([1,2])).groupby("location",as_index=False)
                                   .agg({"ID":'nunique',"Value_Count":'sum'}))
```

---

```
print(out)

  location  ID  Value_Count
0        A   3          6.0
1        B   4          7.0
```

Comment: Thanks @anky - I made a mistake in the question. The values are also repeating. I have updated the dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Roughly same as anky, but then using `Series.where` and `named aggregations` so we can rename the columns while creating them in the groupby.

```
grp = df.assign(Value=df['Value'].where(df['Value'].isin([1, 2]))).groupby('location')
grp.agg(
    ID_count=('ID', 'nunique'),
    Value_count=('Value', 'count')
).reset_index()
```

```
  location  ID_count  Value_count
0        A         3            6
1        B         4            7
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try a very similar approach to other answers. This time we filter first:

```
(df[df['Value'].isin([1,2])]
   .groupby(['location'],as_index=False)
   .agg({'ID':'nunique', 'Value':'size'})
)
```

Output:

```
  location  ID  Value
0        A   3      6
1        B   4      7
```